# CSS rotate animation to make object face the screen

Tags: css, css-animations

I have added this animation to my project 
http://jsfiddle.net/atJdv/5/
but i couldn't manage to rotate the butterfly to be facing the viewer. I am trying to adjust the rotation around the `Y-axis` but it is not working that way.

Any help will be appreciated..

Comment: what do you mean by facing the viewer? like, if it would go up and down and we see both sides?

Comment: yesss, the object will stop flying and moving then take the position that faces the viewer
thanks